# Creating a cash register giving change in euro with correct amounts of each coin/note

Tags: java

So I have to create a program where the user inputs the value of their items  (in cents )  and the money they will pay for the items ( in cents ) . I then need to output the change in the correct euro denominations.

```
public class CR2 {



   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

      int amountdue;
      int amountreceived;

      System.out.print( "Enter the amount due: " );
    if (input.hasNextInt() )

    {
        {

      amountdue = input.nextInt(); 
      System.out.print( "Enter the amount you are paying: " ); // prompt 
      amountreceived = input.nextInt(); // read second number from user 
        }

      if ( amountdue >  amountreceived ) 
         System.out.println( "The amount due must be less then or equal to th amount you are paying");
      int change = amountreceived - amountdue;
      int fifty =5000; int twenty = 2000; int ten = 1000; int five = 500; 
      int two = 200; int one = 100; int fiftycent= 50; int twentycent = 20; int tencent = 10; 
      int fivecent = 5; int twocent = 2; int onecent = 1; 


      if (change > fifty)
      { int changefifty = (change/fifty);
        int leftover = change - fifty * changefifty;

      System.out.println( "50 euro notes amount " +  changefifty  );
        System.out.println(leftover);





      }
    }else { System.out.println("Enter an integer next time"); }
   } 

}
```

So I don't want a whole method on how to do this but just some ideas on how to proceed. I'm thinking I could have 12 if statements  ( one for each euro value ) and then tabulate the values but this seems excessive. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Make an array of denominations start with highest one and find the left over using `%` . Make a loop that does it and keep doing it until the left over amount is zero.

Comment: Thanks that worked.